# Recover funds from a smart contract

Tags: solidity, blockchain

I have deployed a smart contract for a autopool plan, but the plan was expired 3 years ago.
Users transfered funds to this contract. I am wondering if I can get back these funds somehow, since I own this contract. How to send the balance to the owner address.

This is the contract:
https://etherscan.io/address/0x22e84cb17a55d618138911549e28310a84f888de/

Please help me friends! contact: naga.ngl@gmail.com

Answer (score 3):

Who wrote this contract?
There is a function `sendBalance` that allows the owner to take out the ethers. But the function is marked private. Can you provide more details, on why is it a private function even though it is not being called inside the contract?

I don't think there's any other method to take out the funds.

Comment: Yeah it kinda  seems that you've messed up your scam OP, sorry.

Comment: Yeah exactly :)